# Geometric distribution expected value

Tags: probability-distributions

A and B take alternate turns at kicking a football. Their probability of scoring the goal are $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively. The first scorer allows the second one more kick. If the other scores, the game is drawn otherwise the first kicker wins. A begins the game.

If $p_1=p_2=1/3$, find the expected values of kicks in the game.

Can somebody please tell me how to find the expected values of kicks using a geometric summation?

And why is number of kicks = $1/p +1$?(in this case)
Shouldn't it just be $1/p$ since it's geometric distribution?

Comment: What have you tried? As for the mean of a geometric distribution, there are multiple definitions for the geometric distribution; depending on which one you choose, you'll get $\frac{1}{p}$ or $\frac{1}{p}-1$ for the mean.

Comment: @Batman The basic idea is integrating xf(x) where f(x) is the probability density function. Here I can't figure out that function.

Comment: The +1 in the expected number of kicks is due to the first scorer allowing one more kick. Thus if $X$ is geometric, the number of kicks is $N = X+1$.

Comment: Got it. can you also tell me how to solve this by setting up a geometric summation?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is because it's the number of success *before* the first failure: you have to add the failure bace to the denominator.   I also find this confusing.